# How to dynamically add a new object to array of vue (object) data- Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vue.js. I am working on form. I have a add button in my form, as user click on this button same form field will be added to this form. And user can add as many times he/she want. For this my data is .

```
data () {
    return {
      form: [{
          fieldOne: '',
          fieldTwo: '',
      }]
    }
}
```

As user click on add buton in html my addForm fucntion is called.

```
addForm() {
 let newObject = {
              fieldOne: '',
              fieldTwo: '',
          }
 this.form.push(newObject); // Gives error.
}
```

I read about [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set). I can easliy add single field or object. But I don't know how to add object to my form array.
Please help me out.

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[That works](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/d39gdng6/7/).** What problem are you having?

**markup**

```
<div id="vueRoot">
  <button @click="addForm">
    Click Me !
  </button>
  {{form}}
</div>
```

**code**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el : "#vueRoot",
  data : {
    form: [{
      fieldOne: '',
      fieldTwo: '',
    }]
  },
  methods : {
    addForm() {
      let newObject = {
        fieldOne: '',
        fieldTwo: ''
      }
      this.form.push(newObject); // Gives error.
    }
  }
});
```

Even if you're new and just looking around and trying things out, you'll have more fun if you give real names to things. "form" and "fieldOne" will quickly lead into headwreck !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I made some mistake in my code.

Comment: This can always happen :-)

Comment: Can we add this form using Vue.set() ?

Comment: No I don't think so, because you're adding a row to an array, not a property to an object. But there's no need. Vue will react to array changes made with array methods. It's only when you modify arrays with square bracket syntax that you have problems.

Comment: There is any difference in Vue.set() or adding value to object normally ?

Comment: Sure, but it's for adding a property to an object, not a value. In vanilla js, you add a propertythe first time you assign it a value. `myExistingObject.myNewProp = "voila"`. But if you need to add a property to an object already in your `data`, this won't be enough to make your new prop reactive, and you will need `Vue.set()`.